# Add input boxes according to select value of Drop Down

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a selectlist where you can choose a number 1 to 12. Depending on the choosen number I want the same number of input boxes to appear ready to use for $_POST. I can't get the onchange event to trigger any relevant Java?

Edit: I'm realy just fumbling with anything I get at this point:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

function getNPlayers(element) {               
     var element = document.createElement('input');
     element.appendChild(document.createTextNode
     ('some text for testing'));
 }
 </script>
 </head>

<body>
<h1>My Web Page</h1>
<table>
<tr>
<td><select id="NPlayers" sel.onchange="getNPlayers(this)">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Number of players</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>  
</select></td>
      <tr id="other_fields" style="display:none">
          <td>
            Players:<br>
            <input type="tex" value=""/><br>
            <input type="tex" value=""/><br>
            <input type="tex" value=""/><br>
            <input type="tex" value=""/><br>

          </td>
      </tr>
      </tr>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dynamic Textbox</title>
        <script>
            function generate(total,id){
                var drpDown = document.getElementById(id);
                for(i=0;i<total;i++){
                    var child = document.createElement("input");
                    child.id = "test"+i;
                    child.name = "test"+i;
                    drpDown.parentNode.insertBefore(child,drpDown);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id='test' onchange='generate(this.value,"test")'>
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
            <option value='3'>3</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cool, how would I delete the previously created boxes when there's a new onchange?

Comment: Use checking before creation of the input box that whether an input box of same name is still exist or not.